# Draw Canvas on home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-canvas

Wanted a home screen widget on which i can draw text and then get the drawn text from the widget and implement my function. Basically i want to implement canvas on my home screen widget. Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible from an app widget. App widgets do not get fine-grained touch events of the type needed for drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you were able to draw a canvas on widget it will not be that much useful as the screen is bound to slide. There might a possibility of doing so if you had only one screen as your home screen but i don't find that being feasible.
I think your best bet would be to open an activity on click of widget and draw anything on a canvas in that activity.